# Magento 2 display if order status value contains both Delivery / delivery

Tags: magento2, grid, order-status

We have migrated orders data but old orders we have **sales_order_grid** & **sales_order** order status is **Delivered** but in M2 we are considering status as **delivered**

We would like to adjust the order grid column to use both formats. please advise[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this question here are the steps which will help for the stack users if require

1. Create app/code/Magento/Stackexchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">    
   <columns name="sales_order_columns">
       <column name="status" class="Magento\Stackexchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
           <settings>
               <filter>select</filter>
               <options class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options"/>
               <dataType>select</dataType>
               <label translate="true">Status</label>
           </settings>
       </column>  
   </columns>
   ```
2. Create app/code/Magento/Stackexchange/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Status.php

   ```
   <?php
      namespace Magento\Stackexchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

     use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
     use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
    use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

   class Status extends Column


    {
      /**
    * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
    */
   private $orderRepository;

   /**
    * status constructor.
    *
    * @param ContextInterface $context
    * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
    * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    * @param array $components
    * @param array $data
    */
   public function __construct(
       ContextInterface $context,
       UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
       OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
       array $components = [],
       array $data = []
   ) {
       $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
       parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
   }

   /**
    * Prepare Data Source
    *
    * @param array $dataSource
    * @return array
    */
   public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
   {
       if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
           foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
               $order  = $this->orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
               $isStatus = $order->getData("status");
               if($isStatus == 'Delivered') {
                   $isStatus='delivered';
               } 
               $item[$this->getData('name')] = $isStatus;
           }
       }

       return $dataSource;
   }
   }
   ```